# Best and Easy way to parse string template in c# 2.0

Tags: c#, templates, template-engine

here is my pesudo template

```
Dear {User},

Your job finished at {FinishTime} and your file is available for download at {FileURL}.

Regards,

{Signature}
```

i search Google for template parsing in c# and found couple of good library but those library are totally for c 4.0 version. i am working with c# v2.0. so anyone can suggest me any good library for parsing string template for c# v2.0. just discuss briefly best and easy way to parse string template in c# 2.0. thanks

### i got a easy solution with RegEx

```
string template = "Some @@Foo@@ text in a @@Bar@@ template";
StringDictionary data = new StringDictionary();
data.Add("foo", "random");
data.Add("bar", "regex");
string result = Regex.Replace(template, @"@@([^@]+)@@", delegate(Match match)
{
    string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
    return data[key];
});
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program {
static void Main() {
    var template = " @@3@@  @@2@@ @@__@@ @@Test ZZ@@";
    var replacement = new Dictionary<string, string> {
            {"1", "Value 1"},
            {"2", "Value 2"},
            {"Test ZZ", "Value 3"},
        };
    var r = new Regex("@@(?<name>.+?)@@");
    var result = r.Replace(template, m => {
        var key = m.Groups["name"].Value;
        string val;
        if (replacement.TryGetValue(key, out val))
            return val;
        else
            return m.Value;
    });
    Console.WriteLine(result);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Are you looking for a way to replace the tokens in the template with actual values to generate an output string?

Comment: This is too much of a [shopping question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) to fit the Stack Overflow Q&A format.

Comment: i do not know what was wrong with this question for which i got negative mark.i often saw people are very much fond of giving negative mark instead of coming with solution.

Comment: http://dotliquidmarkup.org/ good template engine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why can't you just use string.format? Change your template to this:

```
Dear {0},

Your job finished at {1} and your file is available for download at {2}.

Regards,

{3}
```

And use this:

```
string.format(template, user, finishTime, filepath, signature);
```

No?

Answer (score 0):

It may be too simple, but for this kind of tasks I've always used String.Replace in C#

Comment: String.Replace would be very trivial. suppose my shopping cart template mail then it would be problem for replace method.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest option is to just do string replacement on specifiers. However the problem here is you must know the specifiers before hand.

A more complicated process would be to read in the template as a string and tokenize it. You process each character and emit tokens a parser can use. Really you'd have very few, you'd have normal string characters, some whitespace characters and your token begin/end pair.

You want to keep churning through the tokens until you reach the specifier start token, then record everything until the specifier end token as the token name. Rinse and repeat until you have processed all tokens emitted.

Once you have parsed out your collection of specifiers you can then simply do a string replacement on them like the initial idea. Or if you record where in the string the specifier is, i.e offset and length you can simply cut out and insert with your replacement value.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using `string.Format` - e.g:

```
string template = @"Dear {0}, Your job finished at {1} and your file is available for download at {2}. Regards, {3}";

string output = string.Format(template, user, finishTime, fileUrl, signature);
```